# Accessing an Eager loaded property which is null cause lazy load

Tags: properties, entity-framework-5, lazy-loading, eager-loading, objectcontext

I have eager-loaded a property on an Entity.

If the FK-reference for that property points to a non-existing item (i.e the value -1), the property is (naturally) not loaded. 
However: For some reason, EF still tries to access the databasecontext and perform lazy load of this property when I try to access/check the value of the property in my code.

If the FK-reference is  or an existing FK-Id, everything works ok.

```cs
public Tbl_Car GetCar(int id){
    Tbl_Car car = null;
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        //Explicitly tell EF not to use lazyloading seems to be the only way
        //context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        car = context.Tbl_Car
            .Include("Owner")
            .Where(x => x.Id=id)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    }
    return car;
}

public void DisplayCar(){
    Tbl_Car car=GetCar(1234);

    //I need to check if Owner is null before accessing properties.
    //For some reason lazy loading kicks in and starts complaining about missing 
    //objectcontext
    //NOTE: This only occurs if car.OwnerId is set to a nonexistent entity, i.e -1
    //If car.ownerId=<null> or the id of a owner which existing, all is ok
enter code here
    if (car.Owner!=null){
        Console.WriteLine(car.Owner.Name);  //dont get this far
    }
}
```

Is this behaviour a bug in EF ? 
Maybe it's just me, but in my mind, when you've explicitly eager-loaded a property, EF should not try to lazy-load it at any point even if it cannot find an entity with the given FK.

Comment: It's possible that EF does **not try to lazily load** the navigation property but only tries to access the internal flag (`IsLoaded`) to check **if** the navigation property has been loaded already. You are right that this flag should return `true` and prevent lazy loading because you eagerly loaded the property. But maybe accessing this flag requires an undisposed context. Just a guess.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (if I could I would be in trouble). Is there anything in the getter of the Owner property that could trigger lazy loading, or is it just a simple getter?

Comment: EDIT: 
I've tracked down that my error only occurs if the FK of Car points to a non-existent entry in Owner. 

If the FKvalue (Car.OwnerId) is <null>, everything works as expected. 

If i.e FKValue(Car.OwnerId) is i.e -1, Entity framework tries to lazy-load the entity and the 'ObjectDisposedException' occurs, because EF tries to lazyload outside the dbContext.